# `transitionend` stops firing after several events

Tags: javascript, transitionend

I have a tricky problem. When a user presses on a `div` I want to add a css class to that `div` with name `.active`, using css transition. Then, after a short timeout, I want to handle `transitionend` event where I will remove the class `.active` from the `div`. The problem is, if a user presses on the button too fast, say 15-20 times per second, `transitionend` eventually stops firing.

You can see this effect [here(clickable link)](https://jsfiddle.net/qgrat8s5/), open Chrome browser(I wasn't able to reproduce it in FF) and start clicking on the button as fast as you can. After 15-20 clicks `transitionend` will stop triggering.

I think, when `transitionend` handler is still working, a user can press the button once again and the div will get `.active` class, but it will not trigger `transition` event. The question is - is it possible to write bullet-proof code to clear the `.active` class using `transitionend` event only ?

Thank you.

*edit* embedded snippet below

```js
var blk = document.querySelector('.animated-element');
var btn = document.querySelector('.button');
var ctr = document.querySelector('.click-counter');
var lgr = document.querySelector('.logger');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var currentValue = Number(ctr.innerHTML);
  ctr.innerHTML = ++currentValue;
  if (!blk.classList.contains('active')) {
   blk.classList.add('active');
  }
});

blk.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
  blk.classList.remove('active');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = 'Transition end';
  lgr.appendChild(li);
});
```

```css
.scene {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.animated-element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 500ms;
}

.animated-element.active {
  font-weight: 700;
  /* background-color: #ff0055; */
}

.button {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.click-counter {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 17px;
  min-width: 17px;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  user-select: none;
}

.logger {
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="scene">
      <div class="click-counter">0</div>
      <div class="animated-element">
        <span>ABC</span>
      </div>
      <div class="button">
        Press me several times
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="logger"></ul>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to post enough code that we can reproduce your problem; see the "*[mcve]*" guidelines for help :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! If you follow by the link which I've provided ( https://jsfiddle.net/qgrat8s5/ ), you will find the complete example.

Comment: 'Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]'' - quoted verbatim from the 'close' dialogue. The code must be in the question, in order to guard against link-rot or deletion of the code at a later date, which renders this question useless to any future visitors.

Comment: I embedded the snippet directly in the post, and I was also able to reproduce the problem in Chrome. `transitionend` doesn't even fire in Safari (with this example).

Comment: Oddly enough, if I uncomment the `background-color` rule in the `.active` class, I am no longer able to reproduce in Chrome (ie: the bug goes away). Strange...

Comment: @rossipedia: because the animation of the `background-color` takes time which, I think, seems to prevent the browser from having problems. If `font-weight` is replaced by `font-size`, and `background-color` is removed, ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qgrat8s5/20/)) or commented out ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qgrat8s5/21/)) the problem similarly disappears. I think the issue with `font-weight` is that it increments in jumps of 100, and those 'jumps' require a font that supports the interim weights, which many don't.

Comment: Thank you Friends. Unfortunately the only solution I’ve found so far is to replace `transitionend` with setTimeout, which, in my humble opinion, is less elegant way to remove the `.active` class.

Comment: Maybe it'll be helpful for someone - I filed a bug report at chrome bugtracker, please see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740486). Thank you.